# Where clause that selects all in certain cases

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dropdownlist with options 'dog', 'cat' and 'all'.

If this just had 'dog' or 'cat' there would be no issue I could just write ...

```
var SelectedPets = pets.Where(x => w.species == ViewModel.SlectedDropdownListSpecies)
```

My application has several of these Dropdownlists with several choices + 'all'.

The only way i can see to implement the all option in Linq is with a series of if statements - if the user selects 'all' then the Where is just not used at all.

I'm looking to avoid this kind of code:

```
if (ViewModel.SelectedDropdownListSpecies != 'all')
{
    SelectedPets = Pets.Where(x => w.species == ViewModel.SlectedDropdownlistValue)
}

if (ViewModel.SelectedDropdownlistValue2 != 'all')
{
    SelectedPets = SelectedPets.Where(x => w.colour == ViewModel.SlectedDropdownListColour)
}
```

Is there a way that I can have a Linq expression similar to the above that also somehow honours the 'all' value.

It's a greenfield app so I have a lot of wiggle room in terms of how this is implemented.

I haven't been able to find anything on Google - not really sure what to search for exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
var SelectedPets = pets.Where(x => w.species == ViewModel.SlectedDropdownlistValue || ViewModel.SlectedDropdownlistValue == "all")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a common technique but I love the lateral thinking.